# How to provide/load assets in dart package

Tags: dart, command-line-interface, assets

I currently have a pure dart package that generates a pdf file using some user provided info. The pdf file must contain a static svg image I want to provide with the library.

In a different project I'm writing a headless application that reads the required info to generate the pdf from a file.

I can't understand how one is meant to specify the path to the svg asset in the library, at least when debugging, dart always tries to load the file relative to the root of the running project and not relative to the root of the library. As far as I can see, all the documentation on the official website explains how to handle assets in a flutter app, however neither of my projects depends on flutter.